# Sharing large object between different processes in Python 3.4

Tags: python, performance, python-3.4, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to share a large object (~2 GB) between different processes in Python, in order to cut down on memory usage. I have learned about the Manager class and proxies in the multiprocessing library (https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-managers). However, according to the documentation and to other Stackoverflow users, this can be very slow when it is used on large objects like this one. Is this correct, and if so, is there another faster Python library or function that I can use instead? Thanks.

EDIT: The object I created is a DAG (directed acyclic graph) whose constructor consists of standard python values, though.

Comment: What do you mean by "share" -- read or mutate?

Comment: I mean read. I am not changing the object in any way.

Comment: Have you looked at mmap?

Comment: I have, but have not heard much about it. Is it faster than proxy objects?

Comment: depending on what you are doing, mmap can be very fast.  If you are sharing intricate object trees, maybe not so much, but if you are sharing things that map well to files, then it's just data that stays in memory.

Comment: You're most likely not dealing with a native python data object like a set or list but if you are, you could look into [shared state capabilities with multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes). You can see this falls in the same section as the proxies you mentioned that you had looked at.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to traverse the graph and retrieve values and/or mutate the graph?

Comment: I am traversing the graph and retrieving values, but I am not mutating the graph.

Comment: @AlexanderWhatley please review my answer

Answer (score 1):

If your data is limited to standard values and arrays (no other Python objects) you can use Shared Memory (Value() and Array(), see https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html#shared-ctypes-objects). It is very fast.

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying, but it is a user defined object, whose constructor consists of standard python values though. Would it still work in this case?

Comment: It doesn't look like it works, as my user-defined object is certainly not a ctype ojbect.

Answer (score 1):

One solution to the problem is to make the *graph a processus* which exposes methods that are executed  from other processus using proxies. This means that you have to build a similar class to `manager.dict` and `manager.value`. 
This is done via a producer/consumer pattern. It's called Inter Process Call (IPC) or Remote Procedure Call (RPC). Solutions might involve [zeroless](https://github.com/zmqless/python-zeroless) or [pyro](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pyro4).

Another solutions, that is simpler

Another solution is to use a database. For instance, [bsddb](https://www.jcea.es/programacion/pybsddb_doc/dbenv.html) or [lmdb](https://lmdb.readthedocs.org/en/release/) which support at least multiprocessus read access to the database. Using [ajgu](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ajgu) or [the simpler design](https://github.com/amirouche/AjguDB). Can save you from writing a lot of code.

Last solution, is to build a file that you mmap in memory and read from their. But this is really a solution with your graph is readonly because if you expect to modify the graph you will need to start to write an mmap'ed graph database. This has the advantage of being fully in memory.

My recommendation is to use lmdb to build a graph database taking exemple from the simpler version of ajgu with two script:

- One to create the database
- Another class that will use the graph from different process.